# How to select a tmux window by name?

Tags: tmux

I have several windows including `r-emr_task`, `r-emr_task_bake` and `r-emr_task_fry`:

```
$ tmux list-windows | grep r-emr_task
0: r-emr_task (1 panes) [94x22] [layout 5685,94x22,0,0,54] @54
32: r-emr_task_fry (1 panes) [142x32] [layout 5976,142x32,0,0,55] @55
41: r-emr_task (1 panes) [142x32] [layout d971,142x32,0,0,41] @41
43: r-emr_task_bake (1 panes) [142x32] [layout d973,142x32,0,0,43] @43
45: r-emr_task_fry (1 panes) [142x32] [layout d975,142x32,0,0,45] @45
56: r-emr_task_bake (1 panes) [142x32] [layout d975,142x32,0,0,64] @64
$
```

If I try to switch to the `r-emr_task` window by using the `'` command, and then entering `r-emr_task`, I get the error: `Can't find window: r-emr_task`.

So what I end up doing is using the `"` command and the `/r-emr_task` to search for the window and press ENTER to select it.

Why doesn't the `'` command work?  The tmux man page says:

> ```
>    '           Prompt for a window index to select.
> ```

I've also tried `'` followed by `=r-emr_task` to select exactly that window. I also tried `=0:r-emr_task` to include the session name. No go.

Comment: by default `"` is to split the pane.

Comment: yes!  I have `bind-key '"' choose-window -F "#{window_index}: #{window_name}#{window_flags}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two windows with the same name `r-emr_task`. `C-b '` expects that the "index" matches only one window.

```
 0: r-emr_task (1 panes) [94x22]  [layout 5685,94x22,0,0,54]  @54
41: r-emr_task (1 panes) [142x32] [layout d971,142x32,0,0,41] @41
```